# How to Programmatically render webcomponent as child of another component in VanillaJs?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm trying to learn vanilla webcomponents and I am stuck trying to do something simple and no combination of keywords I can think of return anything helpful in Google.

So in my render method, I see all sorts of examples that manually construct a tag and assign all the attribute, like so:

```
render() 
{
    this.innerHTML = `
    ${
        this.data
        .map(reason => 
            `<${ReasonItem.elementName}
                name="${reason.Name}"
                description="${reason.Description}">
                </${ReasonItem.elementName}>`)
        .join('')
    }
    `;
}
```

This works, but it's extremely tedious for child controls that have LOTS of attributes.

I would like to do something like:

```
render()
{
    this.innerHTML = `
    ${
        this.data
        .map(reason => 
        {
            let child = new ReasonItem();
            child.reason = reason;
            child.render();
            return child.outerHTML;
        })
        .join('')
    }
    `;
```

This almost works, but apparently the constructor and other methods on an HTMLElement can be called out of order so I'm getting 'unidentified' in all my elements since the constructor calls render() and the setting of the property calls render(), but the constructors render is being called after the property is set, so I'm thinking I'm not doing this right.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@connexo So after lots of guess and testing, this appears to do what I need:

```
render() 
{
    this.data.forEach((reason) =>
    {
        const el = document.createElement(ReasonItem.elementName);
        el.reason = reason;
        this.appendChild(el);
    });
}
```

I like the look of this better, not sure if it's equivalent or advisable, perhaps javascript pros can tell me what's 'generally preferred'?

```
render() 
{
    this.data.forEach((reason) =>
    {
        const el = new ReasonItem();
        el.reason = reason;
        this.appendChild(el);
    });
}
```

Internally in my 'ReasonItem', the 'reason' property is observed and when changed, it loads (from the complex reason json object) all the dozens of attributes into their appropriate spots on the ReasonItem component.

Answer (score 0):

> since the constructor calls render()

That should **never** be done in the constructor. Leave that call to `connectedCallback`.

> but the constructor's render is being called after the property is set

That's not possible unless you have an designed an `async` constructor.

Also, if you're not using Stencil or lit which do property binding and updating for you, you shouldn't try to mimic a `render` method to react to updates.

Instead, create your elements programmatically and have the component store references to those elements, so you can make targeted, partial updates later. Use getters and setters for the purpose.

Edit: Your solution code can be simplified:

```js
render() 
{
    while(this.lastChild) this.lastChild.remove();
    this.append(...this.data.map(reason => Object.assign(new ReasonItem, { reason })))
}
```

Also you probably need to empty your host element before rendering if you insist on a `render()` method.

Comment: That is sort of the thrust of my question here, how to I programmatically create the child component, set it's data as one complex object and add the result to the body of my list?  If I'm not calling render on the child component, how do I get the child to render itself within the body of the list container without doing what I did in the first example?

Comment: Add an example of parent and child component, **dumbed down to the absolute minimum necessary** to demonstrate your problem, to your question.

Comment: Thanks connexo, I think it's pretty clear what I'm trying to do from the snippets above.  I'm not asking anyone to try and figure this out for me.  If you know webcomponents and have written a list component before, it should be obvious what I'm trying to do here.  It's the first thing anyone would need to do if you were trying to make a list with the list items containing dozens of attributes.

Comment: I'm asking because if the example is really minimal, I'd rewrite it and add it to my answer.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the child component is, any component.  I just need one component to contain another component without specifying the child as a 'string' first.  I want to do it programmatically and assign a json object to a property and have the child add its own output to the body of the list (like in the second example).

Comment: I understand, but please understand I need an example I can copy and modify. I'm not willing to create an example out of the blue for you.

Comment: ok, no worries, if I have time after work I can try to put something together.

Comment: FYI I heeded your advice to remove the render from the constructor (some tutorial I watched did that) and in doing so I think I fixed another bug I was struggling with, so thank you for that!